# How to understand the behavior of sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, polynomials

In [sklearn doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html), it was introduced that the two dimensional feature of the form [a, b] would get its degree-2 polynomial features as [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2].

However, it's not clear how this happens. I cannot understand if the degree changes to 3, for example, what would the feature be like.

I tried to interpret it by [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2] = the upper triangle of ([a, b] @ [a, b].T ) because it seems like a quadratic form. But this would not be correct for degree 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1, a, b, a², ab, b², a³, a²b, ab², b³] probably. These are the powers in the expansion of (1 + a + b)³.

In the case of three variables, [1, a, a², a³, ab, ab², abc, ac, ac², b, b², b³, ba², bc, bc², c, c², c³, ca², cb²].

Answer (score 0):

This pseudo code explains how the features are generated for a given max degree `n`

```py
polynomial_features = []
for degree in range(n + 1):
    for k in range(degree):
        polynomial_features.append(a**k * b**(degree - k))
```

So, for degrees up to 3 for instance, you would get:

```
# for degree = 0:
# k = 0
polynomial_features.append(a**0 * b**0)  # = 1

# for degree = 1:
# k = 0
polynomial_features.append(a**0 * b**1)  # = b
# k = 1
polynomial_features.append(a**1 * b**0)  # = a

# for degree = 2:
# k = 0
polynomial_features.append(a**0 * b**2)  # = b**2
# k = 1
polynomial_features.append(a**1 * b**1)  # = a*b
# k = 2
polynomial_features.append(a**2 * b**0)  # = a**2

# for degree = 3:
# k = 0
polynomial_features.append(a**0 * b**3)  # = b**3
# k = 1
polynomial_features.append(a**1 * b**2)  # = a*(b**2)
# k = 2
polynomial_features.append(a**2 * b**1)  # = (a**2) * b
# k = 3
polynomial_features.append(a**3 * b**0)  # = a**3
```